# Page container padding equal exact height header

Tags: html, css

I have a simple issue with a *Shopify* store. I've installed a fixed header and added a top padding of `50px` to the `PageContainer` so that the header doesn't overlap with the main content. **However, this results in `50px` of extra space on mobile, which is too much.**

I would be very grateful if you could help me set two different top paddings, one for desktop and one for mobile. **How can I set the top padding of `PageContainer` to be equal to the exact height of the header, regardless of the screen resolution?** Alternatively, is there a way to set different padding for each resolution, perhaps using media queries?

*I started learning about this only three days ago, but I'm quickly learning through Google searches.* I've also found a solution to this issue, which involves moving the header to its own fixed wrapper, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```css
/* Sticky header */
header.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.36);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.36);
}

/* Page Container */
#PageContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header.site-header">
    <div class="PageContainer is-moved-by-drawer">
        This is the fixed header content.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="PageContainer is-moved-by-drawer">
    This is the page content.
</div>
```

Comment: your CSS and HTML have nothing in common - the classes you list in CSS are not used in the HTML

Comment: It's a solution I found in a forum, It's not my html code.

Comment: Looks like you need CSS media queries. Your header will most likely have a fixed height for mobile and desktop. Use media queries to match this value based on screen size.

Comment: @fubar My header don't have a fixed height but I can do it for the desktop one but in small screens I have a completely different header ( navigation bar + hamburger menu )

Comment: @Mars14k - but does the mobile header have a fixed height? Do you have a link to the live site?

Comment: @fubar I can't seem to find another css class for only mobile header, I just start learning web dev so I don't know what's the exact name of that class, there's a mobile.nav but I can only find icons and links stuff inside, when I change header.site-header background to #000, both desktop and mobile headers became black! Sorry I can't share the website here and there's no dm in stackoverflow, please email me at ynakles # gmail.com Thanks! Take a look at my last edit, I'm progressing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make use of CSS Media queries, which will allow you to define different styles for different device sizes, so you can define a `#PageContainer` style for desktop/laptop/tablet sizes, and you can define the same `#PageContainer` style differently for phones.

These are the default Bootstrap media query breakpoints:

```css
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```

So for your application, what you want to do is define `#PageContainer` for large devices as `50px` padding, and for small devices at maybe 20px padding, and maybe even `40px` on medium sized screens. So something like this in your CSS

```css
#PageContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    #PageContainer {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    #PageContainer {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    #PageContainer {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    #PageContainer {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    #PageContainer {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

You really only need the smallest and largest `@media` block, but I've included all of them so you can see what the different breakpoints are and experiment.

You define the core styles, the attributes that will be the same no matter what screen size first outside of the `@media` blocks so you're not repeating yourself unnecessarily, and then define the padding on the same style inside the `@media` blocks, and the browser will combine the global attributes with the `@media` specific attribute for the current screen size to style the content.

#### More information

- [How does the CSS `@media` rule work?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) - MDN Docs

Comment: @stephen-r-smith Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help and taking the time to write to me, however I found another solution. I think I will use percentage because it's much easier. Nav bar height 10%, and margin of the page to 10%. That way will be proportional and never overlap.

Comment: That works too, it depends on how much control you want to have on your page elements. You can also use media breakpoints to show/hide different classes so you can have a nav bar with buttons and text on large screens, and replace it with the hamburger icon - dropdown menu on small screens.

I would take a look at Bootstrap, and specifically the grid layout system for creating responsive layouts, and the @media breakpoints. Long term I think you'll come to really appreciate the flexibility and ease of layout that framework provides.

Comment: @stephen-r-smith Now I see that the header is taking up too much vertical space as a fixed element on desktop, I would only want it to be the top nav bar only plus the logo mark when scrolling, I know that I need to use jQuery to change the appearance, is that too difficult to implement? Thanks again!

Comment: I would seriously look at using the media queries and fixed size nav bars instead of %. On a large desktop display, 10% will be huge, whereas what you really want is maybe 50px on large displays and 20px on small, or something like that, and that's where the @media css hooks give you precise control. If you're looking to shrink the nav bar when scrolling or pin it to the top of the screen, I would take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ and the docs here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: @stephen-r-smith I didn't mention that it has no effect to set the nav bar height at 10%, I just set the padding-top to 8% and I tested the website on several browsers and resolutions. Looks good! Thanks for the links.